# No OpenCl.framework file in library/frameworks

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile

I cannot find an OpenCL.framework file in library/frameworks on OS X 10.11.4. I need it to build a program. The makefile starts with these commands (it was made for windows but could theoretically work on mac).

```
OPENCLINCLUDE=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\include"
OPENCLLIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib"
```

What do I run the makefile with? Just tried double clicking but it doesn't recognize any of the commands. Sorry i'm kind of a noob. I really don't code. I would like to but first I want to use this cool program.